# Rename dynamic file using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

Hi I have multiple file which are having tie stamp (random).

```
PMPRO_Outbound_US05_20170927_114630.csv
PMPRO_Outbound_US05_20170928_115430.csv
```

etc.

I want to rename these files using batch script, could you please help.

```
PMPRO_Outbound_US05_20170927_114630.csv
```

to

```
PMPRO_Outbound_US05_20170927_114630.csv_1
```

Please help.

Comment: different time stamp files are there just need to rename them

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

using a for loop:

```
for /F %%i in ('dir /b *.csv') do echo mv %%i %%i_1
```

Once you are comfortable that it is doing what you intended to do, remove `echo` to perform the actual rename.